# on no account : 'account' means reason?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> On no **account** should the house be left unlocked.

'account' has many meanings, but I think its meaning here is reason.

Do you agree or disagree with me?

Answer (score 2):

> **Under no circumstances** should the house be left unlocked.

> The house should **never** be left unlocked.

Yes, you are right, it means « not for any reason ».

Answer (score 0):

It has the same meaning as:

> In no situation should the house be left unlocked.